# How could I power an IC over the Ethernet?

Tags: power, voltage, adc, integrated-circuit, ethernet

I was looking foward to powering a small Integrated Circuit using only the power provided by the ethernet outlet of my room. Is that even possible?

I've googled and I've found that the voltage that it provides is something in between 2v and 3v. Since it is not a DC voltage, but a random AC one, I believe that it would be not possible to power an IC without having to use some sort of AD conversor or a simple peak detector circuit in order to maintain the voltage.

Am I wrong? Would you have any advises for that case?

Comment: Well, there is the PoE (Power over Ethernet) standard. Maybe take a look at that?

Comment: "What IC" or more specifically "what power consumption" would be a rather critical question.

Comment: Reverted to the original title without the limitation to scavenging imposed by the 3rd-party edit.  It's up to Luis to clarify if PoE would or would not be an option now that the possibility has been raised.

Comment: @Chris -- That isn't correct. The OP references: (1) AC, (2) data voltages not PoE voltages. PoE is an alternative to the premise of the question and is suggested by all in this role (e.g "Have you also considered...")

Comment: @Rev1.0 PoE is not a better option in my case as I'm working with the standard networks that have in ordinary buildings. Thanks, though!

Comment: Luis's original title states his **goal** clearly needs no further clouding by anyone who is not Luis.

Comment: @Chris -- That's silly. It regresses to *never* edit anything. The goal as specified in the title is vague compared to the body which is very specific. That's probably why he accepted the change... *twice* ;-)

Comment: No, I have checked the records and it was *not* Luis who approved your suggested edit, which unnecessarily narrows the question beyond the original goal.  Often people come to stack exchange sites with a goal and tentative idea that may not be the best way of achieving it.  Having a title that reflects the goal, even where the body contemplates one specific method, is the best balance - *especially when that is the title chosen by the original poster*.  Doubly so when you were claiming that the method to which you'd narrow it would not be able to meet the goal.

Comment: This title is confusing, again. From reading the accepted answer and comments, it is clear the goal is to harvest power from Ethernet. "Power an IC over the Ethernet" is highly ambiguous. This question seems to have turned into a pissing match between some users...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are describing using a concept called "Energy Harvesting," but you are trying to use the *data* pairs of the ethernet port as your energy source.

#### Update: Well, let's qualify this a bit...

While extremely interesting (I did my masters work in this area), what you are describing simply will not work *well* in practice for a number of reasons:

1. All versions of Ethernet over twisted pair cable specify differential data transmission over each pair with transformer coupling. That means that there is no DC power path. You have current moving in both directions through an isolating transformer. You will need circuitry to convert and condition it. A lot of the power you will acquire will be more than consumed in the quiescent power of your conversion and conditioning circuits. There will be very little, if anything, left for the load.
2. The line is only active when data is being sent to you (or broadcast). Unless you are creating a structured environment where you control the network, data (power in your scheme) will be unreliable.
3. If you can control the network, just install a [Power-Over-Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet) power-supply in between the network switch and your device. A PoE power source adds DC power (-48V) to the otherwise unused pairs of copper in the category 5 cable (10bT, 100bTx). It can even work with Gigabit Ethernet now by riding data on-top of the power pair (so it serves dual purposes). It's that simple. Why bother with harvesting?

### Design Experiment

Here's a common Ethernet interface chip ([CP2200](https://circuithub.com/parts/SL/CP2200-GQ)) from Silicon Labs.
[image]

#### Here is an abstraction:

[image]

- The characteristic impedance of the cable system is about [100 Ohms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) (which is why you see the 100 Ohm termination resistor in the Silicon Labs figure).
- The nominal peak transmission output current of the CP2200 is 15mA (page 9). It should be noted that there are high current chips available, even ones with programmable current output (such as DP83223).
- At peak efficiency (matched impedance) the load must present the equivalent of 100 Ohms at the transmission frequency.
- The trasmission system uses a 1:2.5 step-up transformer

#### Maximizing Power Transfer:

At the other end (the output of the network jack), the maximum peak current is 6mA (from 15mA / 2.5). It's delivered into an ideal load of 100 Ohms to reach an maximum instantanious power of P = I^2 R = 3.6mW or about 2.5mW,rms (not bad! and 10x higher than my original estimate).

For 15mA maximum output, the output stage of the transmitter adds about 120 Ohms in source resistance.

1. Working backwards you have 200 Ohms on the remote side of the transformer
2. The 2.5 turns ratio results in an impedance transformation to an apparent 32 Ohms on the primary (transmitter's) side of the transformer.
3. That's *480mV* on the primary winding.
4. The transformer steps it up by 2.5X to 1.2V on the secondary.
5. Half of the voltage is lost to the cable impedance resulting in 0.6V peak to the ideal load.

That's P=V^2/R = 3.6mW. It matches the ideal expectation so we're good.

#### Here's the Problem in Practice:

Unfortunately, power delivery isn't the total story. Now you have to be able to use it.

It's bipolar so you need to rectify, de-ripple, and (possibly) step-up (or otherwise convert/regulate). There just isn't a lot of voltage overhead for this.

You are working with 0.6V and you need to transit two diodes in the full-bridge rectifier. Even using low forward drop diode types, you are still looking at around 0.3V (per diode). That means the voltage available (and therefore power) for you to use in your load is basically nothing.

#### Alternate Rectifier Architectures

There are other approaches to harvesting besides the diode bridge, so it isn't impossible, but it's highly impractical to do this.

For example, you could use a half-wave rectifier (most RFID tags I looked at do this) to eliminate one of the diodes (but you lose half the waveform).

In this case, you get

- 0.3V,peak * 6mA (ideal) = 1.8mW (peak) = 1.27mW (rms)
- With only half the cycle generating you're down to about 640uW (micro-Watts)
- Then you have to derate by your transmission duty cycle (the percentage of time you are keeping the transmitter active)

...and that's maximum. If you change your load away from exactly 6mA, you will get decreased efficiency and therefore much less power output that you would otherwise expect due to the impedance mismatch this introduces.

Harvesting rectifier design is an area of active research and there are more efficient ways to use a single diode. If you really are committed to pursuing this, reply and I'll go find some cites/ideas for you.

Comment: Untrue.  The conversion circuitry will not consume all the harvested power if it is well designed - that's what lets RFID for example work.  The need to have a lot of data flowing could be an issue, but has software solutions.  Of course POE is a good suggestion if such a retrofit is possible.

Comment: RFID works for the same basic reason as PoE: by design. The radio field strength in passive RFID applications in general is not chosen by the requirements for noise immunity but to power the RFID tag.

Comment: @MSalters - No, PoE is simple a DC power source, while RFID works by integrating and rectifying the received signal power to power the reply, much as a parasitic ethernet device might.  While RFID is designed with the idea of powering parasitic devices, it's the same principle at work.  With about a hundred ohms of impedance and several volts signaling (at 10 mbit), there's quite likely more signal power available on ethernet than gets received by a typical RFID tag.

Comment: @Chris -- So I've done some back-o'the-envelope and the numbers actually look fairly similar... I'll explain in an edit. Cheers.

Comment: @DrFriedParts That's quite an impressive answer. What I'm working with requires something around 2.5v volts of tension to function properly. Therefore, by using your approach, it would not be possible to make it. There's one thing, though, that I didn't understand well. It is this 100 Ohm resistance. Is it in the cable in between my circuit and the jack, or inherent to the ethernet network system? I'm asking this question because I might not use a cable in the circuit I'm designing, so, without it, it could have more energy to power it.

Comment: @Luis -- It isn't really 100 Ohms in the resistor sense (Google "Transmission Line Theory"). It is the *effect* of the cable on a signal at 10MHz (or 100MHz). RF signals are a bit different in behavior (there are a few more caveats that we gloss over when teaching DC at the introductory level) than your question implies. If you don't use an ethernet cable, the power available to your device will actually be *even less* than estimated above... unless you keep the *entire* cable system to less than about 15cm.

Comment: @Luis -- I would also add that the voltage you need at the load (within reason) isn't important. What you care about is power (voltage times current) because (with some loss) you can convert current into voltage with various circuits. Assuming a perfect converter, 1W could be expressed as 1A @ 1V, or 0.5A @ 2V... see?

Comment: @DrFriedParts Yes, indeed! In this case, I'm working with just about 200u-350u Watts! I think that is low enough to use your approach. Concerning the cable, I will not actually use any cable in this project. It will be plugged directly on the terminals of the jack; so, it satisfies the condition of being less than 15cm, right? Well, thanks for your answers, as a third (out of five) year EE student I can tell that I could understand your approach.

Comment: @Luis -- Cool! Glad to be helpful. 15cm is *total* distance between transmitter and receiver. You must include *all* of the relevant distances (so the wire in the wall between the jack and the Ethernet switch counts too).

Comment: @DrFriedParts oh yeah, so that's a tricky one. Nevertheless, as I'm talking about micro-Watts, and you mili-Watts, don't you think that it is even feasible? With some voltage multipliers, maybe?

Comment: It's close. You should try it! =) I'm guessing something like 0.3V @ 640uW and you need 2.5V @ 350uW... so you have to get from 0.3V to 2.5V with at least 55% efficiency while maintaining an impedance match to the source...

Comment: @Luis -- I'd start with another transformer: in front of the rectifier, after the jack. Try 1:10 step-up turns ratio. It isn't likely to deliver a lot of power, but you should see what you can get out of it. Perhaps you could harvest from multiple ports in parallel.

Comment: @Luis I don't remember who wrote this (maybe ANSI) but the maximum length of a Ethernet cable will be 80 meters between the wall plug and the router

Comment: The solution will be in the turns ratio, but probably in the turns ratio of the transformer already assumed, rather than a second one.  The only reason I'd see for using two would be if that were the only way to get enough ethernet communication functionality to convince the transmitter to talk a lot.  Something's not adding up with the numbers though, as 10 mBit ethernet is supposed to be a bit higher voltage than reported here - though it's possible lots of devices (especially 100mBit capable ones) get away with under-driving.

Comment: @Chris -- yeah, again, agree with you. The problem is that the first transformer is built into the jack inside the network switch, so we don't have any access to it (if we did, just use PoE).

Comment: Oh, it sounded to me like not one, but two transformers were being proposed on the custom device.  I had not contemplated modifying the connected equipment on the other end of the ethernet wiring at all (well, at all in hardware, software might make it easier to get a highly asymmetric traffic ratio, otherwise finding ways to trigger a lot of inbound data using only very brief trasmissions from the parasitic device would be needed).